# Is there an influence of accelaration on the gyroscope data

Tags: android

I want to create an app that measures the horizontal position of the device while accelerating (positive and negative).

My biggest concern is that the gyroscope data will be influenced by the acceleration. Does anybody have any experience with such setup?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibrating_structure_gyroscope

Comment: I'd suggest you to post this question in http://electronics.stackexchange.com/. Maybe there they can tell you more about the kind of sensors used in gadgets.

Comment: @MisterSmith Am I getting this right, that there are no influences of acceleration on a vibrating structure gyroscope used in an Android device?